# How to make dynamic bootstrap modal work on Iphones?

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

There is problem in opening bootstrap modal in iphones.
If i use static modal like below,

```html
<a href="#responsive" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-green ">Add Product<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> 
</a>

<!-- start: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->
<div id="responsive" class="modal extended-modal fade no-display">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        &times;
       </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:red">Add New Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <form name="new" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/addProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

            <div class="col-md-6">

              <h4><b>Category Name <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <select class="form-control" name="cat_id" required>
            <option value="">---- Select Category ----</option>
             <?php foreach($cat['list'] as $rows=>$value){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $cat['list'][$rows]->cat_id; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($cat['list'][$rows]->cat_name); ?></option>
             <?php } ?>    
           </select>



              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Product Name <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="item_name" required>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Small Description <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="small_desc">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Quantity<span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity" required min="1">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Customer Price<span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" required min="1">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Reseller Price<span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="reseller" required min="1">
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Color<span class="symbol "></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="color">
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Availability <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <select class="form-control" name="availability">
          <option value="1">Available</option>
          <option value="0">Not Available</option>
         </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Image <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" type="file" name="userfile" required multiple>
                <img id="output" width="100px" height="100px" />
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light-grey">
        Close
       </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue">
        Add Product
       </button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--  End Modal -->
```

the modal will open properly and i can enter values.

But if use the modal for editing like below,

```html
<a href="#edit<?php echo  $product['list'][$row]->item_id; ?>" data-toggle="modal">
  <button class="btn btn-blue"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </button>
</a>

<div id="edit<?php echo  $product['list'][$row]->item_id?>" class="modal extended-modal fade no-display">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  &times;
                 </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:red">Edit Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/editProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">

            <div class="col-md-6">


              <h4><b>Category Name <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <select class="form-control" name="cat_id" required>
                      <option value="">---- Select Category ----</option>
                       <?php
                       foreach($cat['list'] as $rows=>$value){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $cat['list'][$rows]->cat_id; ?>"<?php if($cat['list'][$rows]->cat_id == $product['list'][$row]->cat_id) echo "selected=selected"; ?>><?php echo ucwords($cat['list'][$rows]->cat_name); ?></option>
                       <?php } ?>    
                     </select>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->item_id;?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->image;?>">
              <h4><b>Product Name <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->item_name;?>" required>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Small Description <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="small_desc" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->small_desc;?>">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Quantity<span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->quantity;?>" min="1" required>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Customer Price<span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->price;?>" min="1" required>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Reseller Price<span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="reseller" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->reseller;?>" min="1" required>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Color<span class="symbol"></span></b></h4>
              <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="color" value="<?php echo $product['list'][$row]->color;?>">
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Availability <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <select class="form-control" name="availability">
                   <?php if($product['list'][$row]->availability==1){;?>
                    <option value="1" selected>Available</option>
                    <option value="0">Not Available</option>
                   <?php } else {?>
                    <option value="1">Available</option>
                    <option value="0" selected>Not Available</option>
                   <?php }?>
                   </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Status <span class="symbol required"></span></b></h4>
              <select class="form-control" name="status">
                   <?php if($product['list'][$row]->status==0){;?>
                    <option value="0" selected>Inactive</option>
                    <option value="1">Active</option>
                   <?php } else {?>
                    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                    <option value="1" selected>Active</option>
                   <?php }?>
                   </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4><b>Image <span class=""></span>
                     </b></h4>
              <input class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile">
              <img src="<?php echo base_url()." assets/uploads/ ".$product['list'][$row]->image;?>" height="50px" width="50px" border="1px solid #FFF">
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light-grey">
                  Close
                 </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue">
                  Update 
                 </button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With dynamic id, the modal will open with light black overlay on it. I can't edit the fields. Nothing is working inside the modal. 
I am Not Understanding What is the problem with dynamic modal. 
If Anyone knows Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things. 1. Move your form tag out and place it like this -

```
    <form action="./admin/editProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="modal-body">
```

2. Give your modal z-index of 999 or so using css like this -

   ```
    <style>
       .modal {
         z-index: 999;
       }

    </style>
   ```